# Send message to another PHP file

Tags: php

Is it possible to have one PHP file send a "message" to specific users on another PHP file?

Note that the "message" needs to be able to received by a PHP file that is already running, so simply calling the other files doesn't make a difference. The image below demonstrates what I want to do:

[image]

In this example, user 1 calls "send.php", which subsequently sends a message to the "receive.php" instances of users 1,2, and 4. Is this possible to accomplish?

#### Additional Information

I cannot log the messages in a central location like a file or database because I would end up querying for messages about once every 100 ms, which would probably overload the database/filesystem. I need it to be instantaneous.

Additionally, I cannot use sessions or cookies because as mentioned the message needs to be sent to several users. Finally, the receiving PHP file doesn't terminate until the user leaves the page (it's really an HTML5 `eventsource` file).

Comment: 1st file would write the message to a database, second file would read from that database in regular intervals.

Comment: @michi Would ajax not work in this case? Same thing, in an interval ...

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I forgot to mention that I don't want to write this stuff to a central location like a database or file because if I were to check in regular intervals (which would be about once every 100ms) I would probably crash the database/filesystem

Comment: @evan I Think ajax would be doing the job, I'm just not familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

You can persist data across pages by using [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) or a [database](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php).

Answer (score 0):

> Additional Information: I cannot log the messages in a central location
>   like a file or database because I would end up querying for messages
>   about once every 100 ms, which would probably overload the
>   database/filesystem. I need it to be instantaneous.

This can be done, but it's not in best practices. You could go about creating a separate file for each of the messages. This is very bad practice.

In terms of your problem with a centralized database, you never know. This may be able to cope with your requests, just try it and find out.

No programmers have got everything right on their first attempt. They have tried something new, and made a mistake... Everyone makes mistakes in terms of finding the best approach to an application.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there may be ways that are a lot more lightweight, but try to use a message broker with pub-sub capabilities (called topics in [JMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) world). They're made especially to transfer high volumes of messages from servers to clients quickly and reliably.

An easy way to create a test system for such a setup could be to use a [STOMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_Text_Oriented_Messaging_Protocol) capable message broker (see [here](http://stomp.github.io/implementations.html) for a list of available solutions) and combine that with a PHP STOMP client (list available on the same page.

Be sure to read [this remark concerning durable subscriptions](http://stomp.fusesource.org/documentation/php/book.html#Durable_Subscribers): as your PHP scripts will most likely not be running at the exact time a message is sent, you'll need the feature that emulates a durable subscription. I don't know all the brokers described on the page mentioned above, but [ActiveMQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_ActiveMQ) does, and it has been around for quite some time, and has a very good reputation.

Answer (score -1):

PHP doesn't work that way. It runs the script and terminates. You need to look up session, or use a database. If you want to get fancy, use jQuery and Ajax.

Comment: In my case the script on the receiving end doesn't terminate - it's stuck in an infinite while loop and looks for information until it is called to stop.

Comment: In that case, it would help if you show what you've started.  I'm not familiar with eventsource and how it integrates html5 and php.  In any case you'd still need a resource that both the sender and receiver shares.  Have you used Session before?

Comment: `eventsource` is basically a glorified HTML5 long-polling method except that it doesn't timeout. So basically what's going on is the client page would use `eventsource` to get updates from "receive.php", which would in turn get information from a "send.php" initialized by another user.

Comment: It seems like eventsource is just javascript integrated with html5.  You can accomplish what you want using Session which you can set in the sender and acquire in the receiver.

Comment: As the question states, I can't use sessions because it will be sent to multiple instances of "receive.php" with different sessions

Comment: How about session entries with different ids for different receivers?